# SQL convert string into datetime in where clause issue

Tags: sql, where-clause

I'm trying to retrieve data from a wordpress database.
I can't find the syntax error in my query, can somebody help me with this?

It's to list the first 10 posts from specific `post_type` and with its `Events_Date` field converted into datetime.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT wp_posts.*, wp_postmeta.* 
FROM ritmica_wp.wp_posts, ritmica_wp.wp_postmeta
WHERE convert(datetime, wp_postmeta.meta_value, 120) > GetDate() 
IN
    (SELECT wp_posts.*, wp_postmeta.* FROM ritmica_wp.wp_posts, ritmica_wp.wp_postmeta 
    WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'event' 
    AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'Events_Date' )

ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value ASC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Please add which DBMS you are using! Also, when you're at it, please be sure to add the exact error message too!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point of the sub-query. Can't you just do:

```
SELECT TOP 10
    wp_posts.*, wp_postmeta.* 
FROM
    ritmica_wp.wp_posts, ritmica_wp.wp_postmeta
WHERE
    convert(datetime, wp_postmeta.meta_value, 120) > GetDate() 
    AND wp_posts.post_type = 'event' 
    AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'Events_Date'
ORDER BY
    wp_postmeta.meta_value ASC
```

**(for SQL Server)**